# I want to make each and every link active when user clicks on it in accordion .bt i have no any idea for this.plz help me

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[here  is a image of coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thmDM.png)

here  i have a jquery code and html code.i have external css also.i have a problem for making active feed,medicine,eggs,birds and summary item.i want also to make active every pages of sub item of given above item.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true,
      active:false,
      heightStyle:""
    });
  });
  </script>

<div class="sidebar">
  <div id="icon-bar">

    <a class="active" href="startpage.php">Home</a>
    <div id="accordion">

      <a  class="" href="#">Feed<span class="caret"></span></a>

        <div id="feeditem"> 
          <a href="feed_purchase.php" >Feed-Purchase</a>
          <a href="feed_consumption.php">Feed-Consumption</a>
          <a href="feed_stock.php">Feed-Stock</a>
       </div>  
     <a href="#">Medicine<span class="caret"></span></a> 

       <div id="medicineitem">
         <a  href="medicine_purchase.php" >Medicine-Purchase</a>
         <a href="medicine_consumption.php"  >Medicine-Consumption</a>
         <a href="medicine_stock.php">Medicine-Stock</a>

      </div>

     <a href="#">Birds<span class="caret"></span></a>

         <div id="birdsitem">
            <a href="birds_purchase.php">Birds-Purchase</a>
            <a href="birds_sales.php">Birds-Sales</a>
            <a href="birds_mortality.php">Birds-Mortality</a>
            <a href="birds_stock.php">Birds-Stock</a>
         </div>

    <a href="#">Eggs<span class="caret"> </span></a>

          <div id="eggsitem">

            <a href="eggs_lays.php">Egg-Lays</a>
            <a href="eggs_sales.php">Egg-Sales</a>
            <a href="eggs_stock.php">Egg-Stock</a>
           </div>
    <a href="#">Summary<span class="caret"></span></a>

           <div id="summaryitem">
            <a href="#">Stock-Summary</a>
            <a href="#">Income-Summary</a>
            <a href="#">Expenses-Summary</a>
            <a href="#">Consumption-Summary</a>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please be more clear or atleast provide an image of what your problem is and what you want to achieve

Comment: Can you please share your code in a jsfiddle link and confirm that you need to make all the accordion elements in open state(active)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using `jquery-ui.js` please try below css

```
.ui-accordion-header-active {
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #0077b3;
}
```

Comment: thanks it works.can you say me how to activate the sub menu of accordion header when click on it.

Answer (score 0):

The information is not so clear but as I understand you want to make thee clicked link active. You can use the script. 'active' is a css style.

```
<script>
    $('div#accordion > a').click(function (e) {
        $('div#accordion > a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```